# How to find the nth term of the sequence: 1, 7, 9, 23, 41, ... (together with a certain rule).

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence in the question is just an example, but in general how does one find the nth term of sequences where the pattern involves something of the form: "multiply by 2 and then add 5" then "multiply by 2 and then subtract 5" then "multiply by 2 and then add 5"...?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A083582 ?

Comment: $2^n\times8/3-(-1)^n\times5/3$

Comment: You can try a [sequencedb.net](http://sequencedb.net/index.html?s=1%2C7%2C9%2C23%2C41) search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n = 2\cdot a_{n-1} + 5\cdot (-1)^n$

TLDR: the solution will have something to do with $2^n$ and something to do with $(-1)^n$

Plugging in initial conditions and solving gives $a_n = \frac{4}{3}\times 2^n + \frac{5}{3}\times (-1)^n$

---

This is a standard linear recurrence.  Break the problem into two parts, first finding the homogeneous solution, then the particular solution, and add these together.

The homogeneous solution comes when only looking at those terms involving $a$, replacing them with powers of $x$, and solving.  In this case $x^n=2x^{n-1}\implies x=2$.  The solutions then appear in the homogeneous solution as those numbers being raised to the power of $n$ times some constant to be found later based on initial conditions.  If there were repeated roots, then have one stay like normal, and for each other of the repeated root multiply again by the next power of $n$ until all are distinct.

For our case, our homogeneous solution will look like $h(n) = c_1\cdot 2^n$

Now, for the particular solution, it will take the same form as what remained.  If there was a constant remaining, we expect a constant in our particular solution.  If there was a polynomial remaining, we expect a polynomial of the same degree in the solution.  If there was a power, we expect a power in the solution.  As before, if there was a repeated root and this coincides with what we expect for a particular solution, multiply by $n$ until it is now distinct.  Be particularly cautious of if $1$ was a root in the homogeneous solution as this is just a disguised constant.  Having plugged it in with your guess at a particular solution, solve.

In your case, $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+5\cdot (-1)^n$ which when plugging in $c_1\cdot 2^n + c_2\cdot (-1)^n$ in place of $a_n$, we get:

$c_1\cdot 2^n + c_2\cdot (-1)^n = 2(c_1\cdot 2^{n-1}+c_2\cdot (-1)^{n-1})+5\cdot (-1)^n$

You'll notice the $c_12^n$ on the left cancels with the $2\times c_12^{n-1}$ on the right.  Continuing the simplifications, we arrive at $c_2 = \frac{5}{3}$

Finally, we can use initial conditions to find $c_1$ by plugging in the start of our sequence, the value of $a_1$.

We get $1 = a_1 = c_1 2^n + \frac{5}{3}(-1)^n$ and solving we get $c_1 = \frac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jordan for his simplification. $a_1 = 1$, then $a_{n} = 2a_{n-1} +5(-1)^n$. We homogenize this recurrence by writing $$a_n + a_{n-1} = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} \iff a_n -a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2} =0$$ Then, using the standard trick for solving homogeneous linear recurrences, we solve the quadratic $$r^2 - r- 2 =0 = (r-2)(r+1)$$ Then $a_n = A2^n + B(-1)^n$. Using $a_1 =1$ and $a_2 = 7$, this becomes $2A-B = 1$, and $4A+B = 7$ which gives us $6A =8 \iff A = \frac{4}{3}$ and $\frac{8}{3} -B = 1 \iff B = \frac{5}{3}$, so we finally have that $$a_n = \frac{4}{3}2^n + \frac{5}{3}(-1)^n$$

Comment: You can use a factor of $(-1)^n$ to deal with the parity. i.e. $a_{n+1} = 2a_n - 5(-1)^n$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One question, why does the trick for solving homogeneous linear recurrences work? How can we assume that the terms a_n and a_n-1 differ by a ratio of r, when they in reality do not?